# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type "XInterceptor"

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, exception, javabeans

I'm getting lost in making sure everything is annotated properly apparently. When i run a service that uses this new code, I get the error below. Isn't the interceptor a bean already with the @Component and then everything it needs to be a bean within is a bean?

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.demo...XInterceptor' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1654)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1213)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1167)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760)
    ... 88 common frames omitted

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have a `someDecorator` class that uses the intercepter that I have made changes to:

```
@Component 
@RequiredArgsConstructor 
public class someDecorator { 

    private final XInterceptor xInterceptor; 
    ...
    private void useTheInterceptor(...) {
      ...
      aList.add(xInterceptor) // and use it for later
    }
}
```

Now the `xInterceptor`, which uses a another class `YProvider`

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class xInterceptor {

    private final YProvider yProvider;

    public ClientHttpResponse intercept(String str, ...) throws IOException {

        Consumer<String> loggingConsumer = yProvider.getLoggingLevel(str);
        // ... use the consumer 
    }
```

The `YProvider` is where it gets interesting, it has a two values. `ZProperties` which is a config class and a consumer map.

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class YProvider {

    private final ZProperties zProperties;
    private final Map<String, Consumer<String>> consumers;

    public Consumer<String> getLoggingLevel(String str) {
       // gets a single consumer from zProperties.getExampleMap ...
}
```

`ZProperties` just captures a map from an `application.yml` file:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "some-config")
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@Getter
@Setter
public class ZProperties {
    private Map<String, String> exampleMap;
}
```

Now to populate the `consumers` map in `YProvider` and to set up `YProvider`, I have another config `ConsumerConfig`

```
@Configuration
public class ConsumerConfig {

    @Bean
    public YProvider yProvider(ZProperties zProperties) {
        return new YProvider(zProperties, exmapleMapToConsumerConfiguration());
    }

    public Map<String, Consumer<String>> exmapleMapToConsumerConfiguration() {
        Map<String, Consumer<String>> exmapleMapToConsumerMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        // add stuff to map

        return exmapleMapToConsumerMap;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I had these files in different packages, I had to add `@ComponentScan` with the package name of where the Intercepter+Provider were and the package of where the config files were.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because you didn't provide the XInterceptor as a Bean in you configuration file.

Try adding this to your ConsumerConfig class.

```
    @Bean
    public XInterceptor getXInterceptor(){
     return new XInterceptor();
    }
```

Comment: Tried it but i need to include a provider in there which then throws NoSuchBeanDefinitionException for ZProperties. I created a bean for a config file for the heck of it. But still get the same exception